# Rails migration to update a model attribute for a collection of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, terminal, rails-migrations

I have a huge database prod that includes a large number of user profiles; I need to do a backfill on all users and update an attribute `passport_country` with another attribute value `country` for each, so I did a migration, see the below:

Users Table:

```
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "country"
  t.string "passport_country"
end
```

New Migration:

```
class CopyUsersCountryToPassportCounty < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def up
    User.unscoped.where.not(country: nil).in_batches do |users|
      users.update_all passport_country: users.country
      sleep(0.01)
    end
  end
end
```

I get the below error each time I to migrate the new migration; any suggestions?

Error:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled

Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `country' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f97fbcf4be0>
Did you mean?  count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly issue a single SQL query which copies the value currently in the `country` column to the `passport_country` column. With that, you don't need to fetch the individual records from the database for update which will make this MUCH faster.

Note that this will issue a single SQL statement. It will not create ActiveRecord instances for each user, will not run any callbacks or validations. It also assumes that both `country` and `passport_country` are regular database columns of compatible types.

```
class CopyUsersCountryToPassportCounty < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def up
    User.unscoped.where.not(country: nil).update_all('passport_country = country')
  end
end
```

See [the documentation of `ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) for details how this works.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, this works well and is way FASTER, doing the update by issuing the SQL query as described above will complete the operation in constant time, right? Regardless of the size of the data in question?

Comment: Well, the database server still has to apply the changes to each record. Thus, it will take longer with more data. Depending on the data type of the column and your database server, it will be likely be between "very" and "rather" fast. But it will be the fastest way you can perform this update, period. Depending on the database, column type, the size of the table and your access patterns, you could also segment the updates by limiting the query to certain id ranges (e.g. 1000 users at a time). But with modern hardware, I'd only bother if the table is larger than, say, a couple of gigabytes.